# Why is this mathematica pattern variable not evaluated?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Apparently these pattern variables don't work like I'd expect.  Here is a simple example:

```
In[264]  :=  1 /. x_ -> {x, f[x], ToString[x]}
Out[264] := {1, f[1], "x"}
```

Why is that last element "x" instead of "1".  The following works as expected.

```
In[267]:= y = 2;
   ToString[y]
Out[268]= "2"
```

thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right-hand side of the rule is being evaluated before the replacement occurs, so you need to use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`):

```
In[1]:= 1 /. x_ :> {x, f[x], ToString[x]}

Out[1]= {1, f[1], "1"}
```

`Rule` and `RuleDelayed` are analogous to `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`).

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

Try `Trace[1 /. x_ -> {x, f[x], ToString[x]}]`. I don't have access to mathematica at the moment, but I believe you'll see that the replacement, in particular `ToString[x]`, is evaluated *before* the pattern is applied, so effectively you're doing `1 /. x_ -> {x, f[x], "x"}`.

Comment: Right, you want to use `RuleDelayed`, that is, `:>` instead of `->` (`Rule`).

Comment: @Michael: You ought to post that as a separate answer, so I can upvote it and the OP can accept it!

Comment: Thanks that was it.  RuleDelayed instead of Rule.